# TypeError: Cannot set property 'key' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

```
class Discount {
    discount;
    constructor() {
        this.key = '';
        this.code = '';
        this.discountValue = 0;
    }
    checkData(searchCode) {
        fetch('discount.json').then ((response) =>{
            return response.json()
        }).then ((obj)=>{
           Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
                obj[key].forEach((data)=> {
                  // console.log(data.code);
                   // console.log(obj[key]);
                    if (data.code === searchCode) {
                        console.log(key);
                        console.log(data.code);
                        console.log(data.discount);
                       this.key = key;
                       this.code = data.code;
                       this.discountValue = data.discount;
                    }
                });
           });

            console.log(this.key);
            console.log(this.code);
            console.log(this.discountValue);


        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Wrong');
            console.error(error);
        });
    }


}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
    document.getElementById('calcDiscount').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        const codeInput = document.getElementById('codeInput').value.toUpperCase();
        const myName = new Discount();

        myName.checkData(codeInput);
    });
});
```

```
    at main.js:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:13
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at main.js:12
(anonymous) @ main.js:34
Promise.catch (async)
checkData @ main.js:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:47
```

Why this code does not work? please help me, i can't understand. Please explain to me the solution of this problem if you know how. It's a discount, taking data from the json, it should return key, code and the value, but does not work.

Comment: I guess there is some issue in your response. are you getting the proper respone from your api ?

Comment: Yes, i am getting a proper response

Comment: @iftwMZ - `this` is incorrect, it is not referring to the class instance. Instead of `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {` use `arrow function`. i:e Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {}`.

Comment: @random Works as charm , thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the `forEach` loop i:e `this.key = key`, is not pointing to the `Discount` class instance.

The normal function as callback will create it's own `this` i:e `Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {`

Instead use arrow based function, which do not have it's own `this` and will refer to the `this` from the outer immediate scope, which is pointing to the class instance.

`Object.keys(obj).forEach(() => (key) {`.

```
checkData(searchCode) {
    // here `this` points to the class instance
    fetch('discount.json').then ((response) =>{
        // this is retrieved from the outer scope, which is class instance
        return response.json()
    }).then ((obj)=>{
       // this is retrieved from the outer scope, which is class instance
       Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
           // The normal callback function, will create it's own this, so `this` won't point to the class instance.
            obj[key].forEach((data)=> {
                // Here, this refer to newly created `this` from the immediate enclosed function.
                if (data.code === searchCode) {
                    console.log(key);
                    console.log(data.code);
                    console.log(data.discount);
                   this.key = key;
                   this.code = data.code;
                   this.discountValue = data.discount;
                }
            });
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ES6 arrow functions.

```
class Discount {
    discount;
    constructor() {
        this.key = '';
        this.code = '';
        this.discountValue = 0;
    }

    checkData = (searchCode) => {
        fetch('discount.json').then (res=>res.json()).then ((obj)=>{
           Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
                obj[key].forEach((data)=> {
                  // console.log(data.code);
                   // console.log(obj[key]);
                    if (data.code === searchCode) {
                        console.log(key);
                        console.log(data.code);
                        console.log(data.discount);
                       this.key = key;
                       this.code = data.code;
                       this.discountValue = data.discount;
                    })
                });
           });

            console.log(this.key);
            console.log(this.code);
            console.log(this.discountValue);


        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Wrong');
            console.error(error);
        });
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

You need to use async await since the call is asynchrounous , the execution doesnt wait for your response and thats why you are getting undefined in your Object.keys(obj)

```
async checkData(searchCode) {
        await fetch('discount.json').then ((response) =>{
            return await response.json()
        }).then ((obj)=>{
           Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
                obj[key].forEach((data)=> {
                  // console.log(data.code);
                   // console.log(obj[key]);
                    if (data.code === searchCode) {
                        console.log(key);
                        console.log(data.code);
                        console.log(data.discount);
                       this.key = key;
                       this.code = data.code;
                       this.discountValue = data.discount;
                    }
                });
           });

            console.log(this.key);
            console.log(this.code);
            console.log(this.discountValue);


        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Wrong');
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```